Azure SQL Managed Instance Windows Authentication
I am looking to migrate from Azure SQL VMs to Azure SQL Managed Instance and I had a few questions related to integrating this with an on-premises Windows Active Directory domain.
We have some legacy applications running on separate Windows VMs. These VMs are joined to a Windows AD domain.
Applications are setup to run as a service in Windows and we use the Log on as option for the service so that we can supply credentials for an AD account that the service will run as. The application will need to authenticate to a SQL database using the same AD account that the application is running as. We do not want to provide credentials in the SQL connection string so we currently use Trusted_Connection = true.
When migrating to SQL MI we do not have access to the underlying host so we can't join the host to our AD domain. Based on some documentation I've come across from Microsoft we can setup a trust-based flow so that we can still use Windows AD accounts to authenticate to SQL MI.

In this document it says that "you will turn your Microsoft Entra tenant into an independent Kerberos realm and create an incoming trust in the customer domain.". Is our Entra tenant going to be converted into a Kerberos realm, and if so is it reversible?

In this document there are different SQL authentication metadata modes. If I use Paired will I still need to sync the Windows AD user to Entra ID?

Is the benefit of the Paired mode that I can have independent users/groups in Entra ID, that are not found in Windows AD, and allow for both Entra ID/Windows AD users/groups to login to SQL MI?

In this document I will need to setup a GPO for a KDC proxy. Am I able to set this up for specific VMs or will it apply to all domain joined VMs?

When my application is running and attempts to authenticate to SQL MI how does the authentication flow work exactly? Does the application attempt to authenticate to the SQL MI resource and then since I'm using the Paired SQL Authentication metadata mode does SQL MI know to find the trust relationship that I setup previously? I'm a bit confused on how exactly that whole authentication flow works.

Do I need to run a CREATE LOGIN [DOMAIN\USER] FROM WINDOWS on SQL MI? Is this also what helps in the authentication flow to determine if the user is from Entra ID vs Windows AD in my previous question?


